# Scalatra: printing the HTTP status code of all APIs

Tags: scala, scalatra

I have a scalatra servlet with multiple REST APIs. For logging purposes, I use the after() method to print out the return status code after each API is called.

```
after() {
  logger.info("request {} {} returned with status code {}", request.getMethod, request.getRequestURL, response.getStatus.toString)
}
```

I have noticed that when a method returns with `halt`, the status code is printed correctly, but when the method return a status code in the last line (without `halt`), the status code which will be printed will always be 200, regardless of real status returned.

For example:

```
post("/users/:user") {

  try {

    //some logic here...
    if(condition)
     halt(InternalServerError("DB error"))  //this will cause status 500 to be printed in the 'after' method


  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      InternalServerError("an unknown error occurred") //this will cause status 200 to be printed in the 'after' method
  }
}
```

The user gets back the real status code (500) in both cases.

Any idea why this happens? Is this a bug?
I posted this question on the scalatra-user mailing list, but the list seems to be quite inactive.

Aliza

Answer (score 2):

(disclaimer: I'm not a Scalatra developer but I have been using it for a project. This is based on me reading the code some time ago.)

This has to do with the way Scalatra is handling thrown exceptions (the relevant code seems to be start from [this one](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/2.4.x/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ScalatraBase.scala#L187)). If the somewhere in `runActions` an exception is thrown (`halt` throws a `HaltException`), the `catch` block of `cradleHalt` will be called and we go to `renderHaltException` which will set the response status code.

It's not exactly the same when you're not calling `halt` but returns an `ActionResult` directly. In that case, `executeRoutes` seems to produce a value which is then passed on to `renderResponse`, which will then call `renderResponseBody` and finally the `renderPipeline`. [This block](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/2.4.x/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ScalatraBase.scala#L438) seems to be the place where the actual status code from an `ActionResult` is actually set. However, the `after` function is already called (it was called in `actionResult`, before `executeRoutes` returns). So what you get is exactly your behavior: when you don't use `halt`, the correct response status is only set in the actual response but not your logging call.

You've probably tried this, but the quick fix to your `InternalServerError` not generating the correct HTTP status code when logged is to simply wrap it in another `halt` call.

As to whether this is a bug, I can't say. I'm guessing probably not, because they did say in the `executeRoutes` documentation that `after` is called before the `actionResult` is passed to `renderResponse`. What was not clear was that the act of rendering `actionResult` also sets the HTTP error code, which you wanted to log before.

You'll have to confirm with them on that :).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I did open a bug but have yet to hear from them. My work-around for now is to wrap everything with halt().